# Packing Circles inside a Circle

Tags: matlab, geometry, packing, nonlinear-optimization

Given  unit circle, and a set of M smaller circles of radius r. Find the maximum radius of the smaller circles that allows them all to fit inside the unit circle without overlap.

I have the following  circles packing in polygon example  [link](http://tomsym.com/examples/tomsym_packing.html)

I want to change equations that say that all circles are inside the polygon

```
theta = 2*pi/N;       % Angle covered by each side of the polygon

phi = theta*(0:N-1)'; % Direction of the normal to the side of the polygon

polyEq = ( [cos(phi) sin(phi)]*x <= cdist-r );
```

to equations that say that all circles are inside the circle, but i don't know how. Can somebody help me?

Kind regards.

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is thus off-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, there are no "sides of a polygon" so there is no analogue to `theta` and you'll need to change every place `theta` is referenced, and all variables that reference `theta` (like `phi`).

Something like the following should work.  I've just copy-pasted the code from your link, gotten rid of `theta` and `phi`, redefined `cdist` and `polyEq`, and made it plot a unit circle in the answer instead of a polygon.  Please ask if any of these choices are unclear.

```
M = 19; % number of circles to fit

toms r              % radius of circles
x = tom('x', 2, M); % coordinates of circle centers

clear pi % 3.1415...

cdist = 1;          % radius of unit circle

%%%%%% equations saying all circles are inside of unit circle
polyEq = (sqrt(x(1,:).^2 + x(2,:).^2) + r <= cdist);

% create a set of equations that say that no circles overlap
circEq = cell(M-1,1);
for i=1:M-1
    circEq{i} = ( sqrt(sum((x(:,i+1:end)-repmat(x(:,i),1,M-i)).^2)) >= 2*r );
end

% starting guess
x0 = { r == 0.5*sqrt(1/M), x == 0.3*randn(size(x)) };

% solve the problem, maximizing r
options = struct;
% try multiple starting guesses and choose best result
options.solver = 'multimin';
options.xInit = 30; % number of different starting guesses
solution = ezsolve(-r,{polyEq,circEq},x0,options);

% plot result
x_vals = (0:100)./100;
plot(sqrt(1 - x_vals.^2),'-') % top of unit circle
plot(-1.*sqrt(1 - x_vals.^2),'-') % bottom of unit circle
axis image
hold on
alpha = linspace(0,2*pi,100);
cx = solution.r*cos(alpha);
cy = solution.r*sin(alpha);
for i=1:M
    plot(solution.x(1,i)+cx,solution.x(2,i)+cy) % circle number i
end
hold off
title(['Maximum radius = ' num2str(solution.r)]);
```

Comment: now i have error                    

http://www.screencapture.ru/uploaded/37/ce/36/37cE361d.jpg

Comment: I've corrected the syntax in my answer so you shouldn't get that error.  However, you should try to understand why I've written this answer and what error messages mean so you can fix it yourself and be able to do this yourself in the future.